# Get an image from a 4 dimensions Numpy array as a 4 dimensions Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I've just started to learn Python. I'm using Numpy, and this is on of the things that I don't understand.

I have a Numpy array with Shape (960, 200, 200, 1). I use it to store images of size 200x200x1 (200 height x 200 width x 1 channel). So, I think it means that I have 960 images.

Now, I have to get one image to test my CNN network, to do it, I did it:

```
D = ... # My Dataset with shape (960, 2, 200, 200, 1)

features = D[:,0,:] # Shape (960, 200, 200, 1)
labels = D[:,1,:] # Shape (960, 200, 200, 1)

print("D shape: ", D.shape)
print("Features shape: ", features.shape)
print("Labels shape: ", labels.shape)

print(features[0, :].shape) # Shape (200, 200, 1)
print(labels[0,:].shape) # Shape (200, 200, 1)
```

This code outputs:

```
D shape:  (960, 2, 200, 200, 1)
Features shape:  (960, 200, 200, 1)
Labels shape:  (960, 200, 200, 1)
(200, 200, 1)
(200, 200, 1)
```

I want to get one image from features and one from labels. I have tried these two commands, getting and image with the same shape `(200, 200, 1)`:

```
features[0, :]
features[0]
```

But I need to get an image with shape `(1, 200, 200, 1)`.

How can I do it to get an image with that shape?

Maybe creating a 4 dimensions Numpy Array, and adding the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = np.random.random((200,200,3))
A.shape
```

gives

```
(200, 200, 3)
```

You can use

```
B = np.expand_dims(A,0)
```

and then

```
B.shape

(1, 200, 200, 3)
```